# PHP readdir() and returning a falsy value

Tags: php, boolean, readdir

According to information on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php, the `readdir()` function

> may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE.

and accordingly advises using `===` for testing.

What possible non-boolean value might this be? In my testing, I can only get a false `false`, as it were, in the following example:

```
$dirname='0';   //  misinterpreted
print $dirname==false?'false':'true';
```

All other strings are interpreted as `true`.

Are there any other strings which would evaluate to false? Or is there some other return result which would evaluate as false?

Comment: The manual for the Boolean type lists all values that get considered as false: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: @04FS Thanks for the reference. That would suggest that the _only_ name to worry about is `0`. Does `readdir()` return anything other than `false` or a string?

Comment: readdir _“returns the entry name on success or FALSE on failure”_ - so that should never be anything but a string, unless it is actually false.

Comment: @04FS Thanks. Can you put your comments in the form of an answer so that I can accept it, and close of this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any other strings which would evaluate to false? Or is there some other return result which would evaluate as false?

The manual for the Boolean type lists all values that get considered as false, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting:

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integers 0 and -0 (zero)
> - the floats 0.0 and -0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements
> - the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

And [`readdir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)

> [r]eturns the entry name on success or FALSE on failure

- so unless you are getting false, the value should always be a string. (Directory entries are always considered string values, on that level the concept of a “number” does not exist.)